# Creating a project in Visual Studio 2015 only shows a webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm a newbie in MVC and I'm trying to create an exercise project, but whenever I try to do so it only gives me a webpage, I can't find the folder structure that you would normally see after creating a project. The last image below is what I'm getting every time I create a project.

This is how I created the project.
[image]

[image]

This is the outcome everytime I create a project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have closed Solution Explorer.

Click the View menu and then Solution Explorer to re-display it.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for taking up time answering this newbie question. Appreciate it!